# How to configure internet for one 'super' router and four routers underneat

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, subnet

In our home we have one Ziggo (dutch cable internet provider) router and we are stuck with one unfortunately.
However, as we have 4 households (appartements) that all should connect to this router, we wish to all have our own router and subnet so we can't access each others devices.
Now I was wondering, how would you configure the subnets and the DHCP on each device?
I was thinking of creating a different DHCP range for each router (as the main router doesn't need to know about the DHCP setup on the household routers)
[image: Image of set-up]

Would love to hear your opinion :)

Comment: Hook up the WAN port of each sub router to a LAN port on the main router network. Give each sub router a different IP range than the main network. Then devices on each sub router will not see the other sub routers.

Comment: yes that was my thought as well. And it's better that the DHCP settings are all different on each 'household' router, or does that not matter at all?

Comment: If you connect WAN on a sub router to a source (LAN on the network), then it does not matter what the internal subnets are. They can be the same or different. You might (simply for organization) make them different. I have done it both ways.  Let me know, please, it you are happy with the above and I will post it as an answer

Comment: I am happy but I think it would be best for the noobies to add a more elaborate explenation. Thereby as example, include reference to my image, add DHCP ranges and add IP's for each individual router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely **possible**:

By default most routers have DHCP enabled. Just connect each of them from their WAN-Port to one of the LAN-Ports on the Main Router.

The specific DHCP-Range of each of those routers does not matter (exception: see next paragraph) and even **having the same range for the 4 routers should not be a problem** since those routers are not aware of what is going on behind the other 3 routers (but having **multiple ranges** might make it **easier to distinguish** to which of the networks they are connected **if some users use more than one of these networks**).

I'm not entirely sure if this is necessary but from my understanding **the DHCP Range of the Main Router should be different from the DHCP Range of the other 4 routers** (even though those 4 can be the same). If this is not the case the "Sub-Routers" might be confused which network is talking to them.

[image: Example setup with both different and matching DHCP ranges on the subrouters]

This picture shows a mixture of both having different and the same DHCP Ranges on the sub-routers: Routers #2 and #3 both feature range 192.168.20.0/24 (192.168.20.1 - 192.168.20.255) but they are not shared between both routers. Devices on Router #2 can still not see devices on Router #3 and both routers will asssign the IPs independently.

I use two routers "in series" myself since I need the router supplied by my ISP but need  additional flexibility that my ISPs router doesn't offer.

Additional Information that might add a **second option** to your situation:

*I don't need multiple routers but I have multiple VLANs (Virtual LANs; with different DHCP ranges) that prevent devices from talking from one VLAN to another (one VLAN for my own devices, one for guests etc.). I don't know the specific situation you are in but if the networks are managed by one person only anyway and privacy is not to big of a concern you could also add just one "high end" router and then add multiple VLANs and use a managed switch to split them up for the different households. Buying one good router, a managed switch and four (or potentially less; you might be able to have multiple SSIDs/ Wifi-names per access point) access points could actually turn out cheaper but this depends heavily on your specific situation.*

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you wish to do.

For each sub-router:

Hook up the WAN port to a LAN port on the Main Network.
Make sure the DHCP is enabled in the LAN section of each sub-router (that is normally the default way).
Make an IP Range for each sub-router. The exact IP range does not really matter - it can be different for organizational purposes.

Done this way, users on one sub-router cannot see users on another sub-router.

I have done this both ways in my setups here.